# You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server?

Tags: apache-httpd, phpmyadmin

So I just installed phpmyadmin on my server. When accessing the IP-address/phpmyadmin it said: You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.
Here's part I configured phpmyadmin.

```
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
 # Apache 2.4
 <RequireAny>
   Require ip 127.0.0.1
   Require ip ::1
   Require all granted
 </RequireAny>
```

I'm running apache 2.4.6.

Comment: Please specify the Linux distribution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235363/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-server

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Im running centos 7.2 on amazon instance EC2.

Comment: @123 I read that before but none of those fix worked.

Comment: Does your web server user (e.g. nobody) have read access (POSIX permissions) to the files under phpmyadmin?

Comment: So that means i have to change permission all the file under phpmyadmin folder?